# Differencing and Stationarity in Panel Data Analysis

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, differencing

As far as I know, the source of randomness is different in cross-sectional and time-series analysis.

The following is my understanding.

When we use a cross-sectional data set $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$, the source is the sampling error. A variable $X$ is random because the sample is drawn randomly.

And, when we use a time-series data set $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^{T}$, the source is unobservable shocks. That is, a variable $X$ is random because its components are stochastic. (e.g., $X_t=X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,1)$)

Thus, I think, the sources are totally different.

So, here is my question.

Suppose that we have a panel data set $\{X_{it}\}$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ and $t=1,\ldots,T$.

When we consider a large $N$ and fixed $T$ situation, we assume that the randomness comes from sampling error at the first wave.

Then, in panel data analysis, is it conceptually weird to think $E[X_{t}-X_{t-1}]$ is time-invariant?

Differencing is a common practice to make a (weak) stationary process in time-series analysis.

But, I am not sure whether the same practice is not problematic even though we think that the randomness comes from the sampling error.